# Ошибка 403 и её решения? А так же игнорирование

Tags: php, mysqli

Такой вопрос:
Когда перехожу по ссылке, которая отсылает меня личный кабинет (генерирующий по данным из БД). Пример кода:

```
<a href="<? 'office.php?id='. $_SESSION['id']; ?>">Личная страница </a>
```

Выходи ошибка 403:

> Доступ запрещён!
>   У Вас нет прав доступа к этому объекту. Файл недоступен для чтения,
>   или сервер не может его прочитать.
>
> Если Вы считаете, что это ошибка сервера, пожалуйста, сообщите об этом
>   веб-мастеру.
>
> Error 403 localhost Apache/2.4.38 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.3.3

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это решить? Я читал об этой ошибке, все ссылались на документ .htacces, которого у мне нету. Что должно быть в нём и нужен ли он вообще.

На сколько я понял, у сайта нету доступа к этой странице, но если заходить через авторизацию, то он сразу кидает на эту страницу без какой-либо ошибки.

Если не много видоизменяю код, то он просто игнорирует какие-либо взаимодействия с ссылкой.

```
      <a href="<?php 'office.php?id='. $_SESSION['id']; ?>">Личная страница </a>
```

Comment: Мало что понял, объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю так (у Вас не было вывода значения, соответственно ссылка пуста):

```
<div>
   <a href="<?= 'office.php?id='. $_SESSION['id'] ?>"> Личная страница </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Я просто уже много способов перепробовал, где указывал переменной, откуда ей брать ID, потом показывал переменной куда отправлять этот ID, чтобы перейти на сгенерируемую страницу.

В итоге, он меня просто игнорировал, а ошибку выдавал не на странице, а в том месте, где обычно указывает, куда перейдёт пользователь, в случае перехода.

Как-то сложно. Но как-то так.

Comment: Вячеслав, тогда нужен весь исходный код

Comment: Я новенький на сайте, подскажите пожалуйста, как разместить полностью код, чтобы он не исказил его?

Comment: Фактически чтобы вам помочь мне нужна та часть где открывается сессия и где пишете id

Comment: <?php
session_start();
echo session_id();

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

  $address_mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","project_board");

  $address_mysqli->set_charset("utf-8");
  $project_id=$address_mysqli->query("SELECT `headline` FROM `projects`");
?> 
Здесь указывается начало сессии.

Comment: <section>
    <div>
       <a href="<?php 'office.php?id='. $_SESSION['id'] ?>"> Личная страница </a>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <?php
      while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($project_id)) {
        echo $result['headline'];
      }

      $project_id=$address_mysqli->query("SELECT `headline` FROM `projects` WHERE `headline`='data'");
      $result=mysqli_fetch_array($project_id);
      echo $result['headline'];
       ?>
    </div>
    <div></div>
  </section>

А тут указывает, куда положить.

Comment: А надо понять, как указать ID, чтобы $_SESSION его нашёл.

Comment: $_SESSION его не находит вы должны присвоить значение $_SESSION['id']=<нужное вам значение>, до этого сделав session_start (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Дмитрий, к сожалению не помогло. session_start() указан в самом начале документа.

Может мне стоит больше информации указать, чтобы больше шансов появилось, помочь мне в вопросе?